# How to insert an emoji using adb shell input?

Tags: adb, shell, emoticons, development

I've been trying to insert emojis into my android phone using ADB.

`adb shell input text "..."`

works for inserting text, but when I tried to insert an emoji using the unicode(\uD83E\uDD70), I am only getting the raw text inserted. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Seems like this is not possible with plain adb. But with the help of an app that acts as virtual keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23482717/150978